# "main" button scroll with android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

Tags: java, android, nestedscrollview

thank you in advance for taking the time to read.
I've been with a project on Android using Java for weeks. But I have had this problem for days, I tried many things but nothing worked.

What happens is that the "main" button (black color) that expands the other buttons is; scrolls. Before and after expanding the other buttons.

Ideally, it should stay fixed in place before and after pressing.
And that the other white buttons do scroll below the black button.

I attach the complete XML and screenshots.

We open the application and it will look like this:

[][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExwgJ.png

Then we scroll and ideally nothing happens, but the main button is hidden behind the text box.

[][2]
[][3]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZqAA.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gszP.png

We press the main button and as it should be, the other buttons expand.

[][4]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6km3.png

But we scroll and the buttons instead of getting under the black button, they scrooll all the buttons including the black one.

[][5]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RDnO.png

Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCompartir"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/iconcompartir"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
        />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnContacto"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
        android:background="@drawable/iconcontacto"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnDonar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="121dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icondonar"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnEstrella"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="179dp"
        android:background="@drawable/iconestrella"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnWeb"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="237dp"
        android:background="@drawable/iconweb"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Subrayado"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCompartir"
        android:layout_marginTop="-17dp"
        android:editable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Inicio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnEstrella"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Inicio"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#020000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/presentacion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fondotexto"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/status_bar_item_app_background"
        android:drawablePadding="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Esta sección le dará información sobre esta aplicación. Pero si se encuentra en una situación de supervivencia en este momento, omita este comunicado y salte directamente a la sección que contiene la información para su problema / necesidad inmediata."
        android:textColor="#D8D4D4"
        android:textSize="18dp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu

            android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Subrayado"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
            app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@android:color/black"
            app:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_expandDirection="down">




            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnMultiherramientas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconmultiherramientas"
                app:fab_title="Multiherramientas" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnAreasHostiles"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconareashostiles"
                app:fab_title="Áreas hostiles" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPeligrosPorElHombre"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconpeligrosporelhombre"
                app:fab_title="Peligros hechos por el hombre" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnDefensaPersonal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/icondefensapersonal"
                app:fab_title="Defensa personal" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPersonas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconpersonas"
                app:fab_title="Personas" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnInsectos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconinsectosyaracnidos"
                app:fab_title="Insectos y arácnidos" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPescados"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconpescadosymoluscos"
                app:fab_title="Pescados y moluscos" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnCruce"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconcrucedeagua"
                app:fab_title="Cruce de agua" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnCuerdas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconcuerdasynudos"
                app:fab_title="Cuerdas y nudos" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnDireccion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconencontrardireccion"
                app:fab_title="Encontrar dirección" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnCamuflaje"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconcamuflaje"
                app:fab_title="Camuflaje" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnSeñalizacion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconsenializacion"
                app:fab_title="Señalización" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnTropical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/icontropical"
                app:fab_title="Tropical" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnFrio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconfrio"
                app:fab_title="Frío" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnMar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconmar"
                app:fab_title="Mar" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnDesierto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/icondesierto"
                app:fab_title="Desierto" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPlantasVenenosas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconplantasvenenosas"
                app:fab_title="Plantas Venenosas" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPlantas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconplantas"
                app:fab_title="Plantas" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnEnergia"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconenergia"
                app:fab_title="Energía" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnAnimales"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconanimales"
                app:fab_title="Animales" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnRefugios"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="eventoRefugios"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconrefugio"
                app:fab_title="Refugios" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnHerramientas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="eventoHerramientas"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconherramientas"
                app:fab_title="Herramientas" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnComida"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="eventoComida"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconcomida"
                app:fab_title="Comida" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPsicologia"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="eventoPsicologia"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconpsicologia"
                app:fab_title="Psicología" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnKits"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="eventoKits"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconkits"
                app:fab_title="Kits" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnFuego"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="eventoFuego"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconfuego"
                app:fab_title="Fuego" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnAgua"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="eventoAgua"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconagua"
                app:fab_title="Agua" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnMedicina"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="eventoMedicina"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconmedicina"
                app:fab_title="Medicina" />


        </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>



    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>





    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/presentacion2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
                android:text="Esta aplicación está diseñada para guiarte en tiempos difíciles, pero también se puede usar para divertirte al aire libre y aprender cosas que son útiles incluso fuera de una situación de supervivencia. Las partes divertidas también son útiles para entrenar habilidades importantes para posibles situaciones de supervivencia. la lectura es solo un factor: la práctica y la comprensión también son necesarias para aumentar sus posibilidades de supervivencia."
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/presentacion3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginVertical="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="El uso de toda la información que contenga esta aplicación es libre."
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/presentacion4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginVertical="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="Dicho esto, feliz supervivencia. Tengo la esperanza de que nunca te metas en tantos problemas como para que realmente necesites esta guía, diviértete preparándote para situaciones potenciales y aprender."
                android:textSize="18dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>





</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeTop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCompartir"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/iconcompartir"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnContacto"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
        android:background="@drawable/iconcontacto"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnDonar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="121dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icondonar"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnEstrella"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="179dp"
        android:background="@drawable/iconestrella"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnWeb"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="237dp"
        android:background="@drawable/iconweb"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Subrayado"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCompartir"
        android:layout_marginTop="-17dp"
        android:editable="false"
        android:enabled="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Inicio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnEstrella"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Inicio"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#020000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/presentacion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fondotexto"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/status_bar_item_app_background"
    android:drawablePadding="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:text="Esta sección le dará información sobre esta aplicación. Pero si se encuentra en una situación de supervivencia en este momento, omita este comunicado y salte directamente a la sección que contiene la información para su problema / necesidad inmediata."
    android:textColor="#D8D4D4"
    android:textSize="18dp" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="100dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/presentacion2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
                android:text="Esta aplicación está diseñada para guiarte en tiempos difíciles, pero también se puede usar para divertirte al aire libre y aprender cosas que son útiles incluso fuera de una situación de supervivencia. Las partes divertidas también son útiles para entrenar habilidades importantes para posibles situaciones de supervivencia. la lectura es solo un factor: la práctica y la comprensión también son necesarias para aumentar sus posibilidades de supervivencia."
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/presentacion3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginVertical="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="El uso de toda la información que contenga esta aplicación es libre."
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/presentacion4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginVertical="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="Dicho esto, feliz supervivencia. Tengo la esperanza de que nunca te metas en tantos problemas como para que realmente necesites esta guía, diviértete preparándote para situaciones potenciales y aprender."
                android:textSize="18dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Subrayado"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left"
        app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@android:color/black"
        app:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@android:color/white"
        app:fab_expandDirection="down">


        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnMultiherramientas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconmultiherramientas"
            app:fab_title="Multiherramientas" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAreasHostiles"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconareashostiles"
            app:fab_title="Áreas hostiles" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPeligrosPorElHombre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconpeligrosporelhombre"
            app:fab_title="Peligros hechos por el hombre" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnDefensaPersonal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/icondefensapersonal"
            app:fab_title="Defensa personal" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPersonas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconpersonas"
            app:fab_title="Personas" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnInsectos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconinsectosyaracnidos"
            app:fab_title="Insectos y arácnidos" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPescados"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconpescadosymoluscos"
            app:fab_title="Pescados y moluscos" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCruce"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconcrucedeagua"
            app:fab_title="Cruce de agua" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCuerdas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconcuerdasynudos"
            app:fab_title="Cuerdas y nudos" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnDireccion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconencontrardireccion"
            app:fab_title="Encontrar dirección" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCamuflaje"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconcamuflaje"
            app:fab_title="Camuflaje" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSeñalizacion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconsenializacion"
            app:fab_title="Señalización" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnTropical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/icontropical"
            app:fab_title="Tropical" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFrio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconfrio"
            app:fab_title="Frío" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnMar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconmar"
            app:fab_title="Mar" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnDesierto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/icondesierto"
            app:fab_title="Desierto" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPlantasVenenosas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconplantasvenenosas"
            app:fab_title="Plantas Venenosas" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPlantas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconplantas"
            app:fab_title="Plantas" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnEnergia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconenergia"
            app:fab_title="Energía" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAnimales"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconanimales"
            app:fab_title="Animales" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnRefugios"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="eventoRefugios"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconrefugio"
            app:fab_title="Refugios" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnHerramientas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="eventoHerramientas"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconherramientas"
            app:fab_title="Herramientas" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnComida"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="eventoComida"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconcomida"
            app:fab_title="Comida" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPsicologia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="eventoPsicologia"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconpsicologia"
            app:fab_title="Psicología" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnKits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="eventoKits"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconkits"
            app:fab_title="Kits" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFuego"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="eventoFuego"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconfuego"
            app:fab_title="Fuego" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAgua"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="eventoAgua"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconagua"
            app:fab_title="Agua" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnMedicina"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="eventoMedicina"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@android:color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/iconmedicina"
            app:fab_title="Medicina" />


    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I can't press the main button, it just doesn't do anything like it's not a button :/

Comment: Try the edited answer, You just have to adjust the scroll view and fab button placement.

Comment: There I tried and it does let me press (and the other buttons expand) but it does not let me scroll. I have been researching and from what I see in most examples they use no more than 3 buttons that expand. It will be that they do not allow only the expanding buttons to scroll except the main button. anyway thank you very much!